# How to Split with particular condition in Java?

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have a string like

```
"resources/json/04-Dec/someName_SomeTeam.json"
```

In above string I want just "04-Dec" part, this may change to "12-Jan" like this or any date with month with that format. How do I do this?

Comment: Why not check javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split using `/` and get the value `2`

```
String text = "resources/json/04-Dec/someName_SomeTeam.json";
String[] split = text.split("\\/");
String result = split[2];//04-Dec
```

Or you can use patterns with this regex [`\d{2}\-\[A-Z\]\[a-z\]{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/B1wcMA/1/):

```
String text = "resources/json/04-Dec/someName_SomeTeam.json";
String regex = "\\d{2}\\-[A-Z][a-z]{2}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```